# ExtJs Apply an opacity to layer by slider

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I want to apply transparency to a layer saved previously, to do this i have a treepanel that contains all layers listed, and by itemcontextmenu event I put a slider to manage the opacity, when i select the first element to change the opacity of the layer works well, but when i select another item/element, the opacity still set with the first element.....

For example:
First element selected (works fine):
[image]

Next element selected (it still use the previous element):
[image]

I have this code:

```
initComponent: function() {
    var anchoPanatallaRes = window.screen.width;
    var altoPantallaRes = window.screen.height;

    var anchoTOC = 330;
    var altoTOC = 473;

    if (anchoPanatallaRes <= 1024) {
        anchoTOC = 282;
        altoTOC = 373;
    }

    function addUrl(value, p, record) {
        return value ? Ext.String.format(
                '<a href="'+value+'"target="_blank"'+'>Ver metadato'+'</a>'
        ):'';
    }

    var treeStore = Ext.getStore('capa');

    var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
        title: '',
        id: "arbolTabla", 
        width: anchoTOC,
        height: altoTOC,            
        reserveScrollbar: true,
        loadMask: true,
        useArrows: true,
        rootVisible: false,
        store: 'capa',
        allowDeselect : true,
        border : true,
        animate: true,
        columns: [{
            xtype: 'treecolumn',
            text: 'Capa',
            flex: 5,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'titulo'
        },{
            text: 'Metadato',
            flex: 2,
            dataIndex: 'metadato',
            renderer: addUrl
        }],

        tbar: [{
            labelWidth: 100,
            xtype: 'triggerfield',
            id: 'campoBusquedaCapa',
            fieldLabel: 'Nombre capa:',
            triggerCls: 'x-form-clear-trigger',
            onTriggerClick: function() {
                this.reset();
                treeStore.clearFilter();
                this.focus();
            },
            enableKeyEvents: true
        }, {
            xtype : 'button',
            icon: 'css/app/imagenes/lupa.png',
            cls : 'apagarCapas',
            width: 20,
            height: 25,
            id : 'btnApagarCapas',
            action: 'apagarCapas',
            tooltip : 'Apagar todas las capas',
            padding:0
        }]
    });

    Ext.apply(this, {
        title: 'TABLA CONTENIDO',           
        constrain: true,
        header : {
            titlePosition : 2,
            titleAlign : 'center'
        },
        closable : false,
        width : anchoTOC,
        height : altoTOC,
        x : 20,
        y : 270,
        layout : 'fit',
        animCollapse : true,
        collapsible : true,
        collapseDirection : Ext.Component.DIRECTION_LEFT,
        items: [tree],
    });

    tree.on('itemcontextmenu', function(view, record, item, index, event, eOpts) {
        event.stopEvent(); 
        if (record.data.leaf != false) {

            slider = Ext.create('Ext.slider.Single', {
                id: 'sliderOpacidad',
                hideLabel: true,
                floating: true,
                width: 200,
                minValue: 0,
                maxValue: 100,
                value : 70,
                listeners: {
                    change: function (newValue, thumb, eOpts ){
                        var capaBuscar = record.data.id;
                        var controladorUbicar = aplicacion.getController("ControlUbicar");
                        var capa =  controladorUbicar.buscarcapa(capaBuscar);
                        console.log(capa);
                        capa.setOpacity(thumb/100);
                    },
                    blur: function() {
                        slider.setVisible(false);
                        capaBuscar=null;
                    }
                }
            });
            slider.showBy(item, 'tl-tl', [event.getX() - view.getX(), 12]);
        }
    }, this);
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

Comment: possible for you to create a fiddle?

Comment: it's a bit complex because the server with the layers doesn't mine, i can create the fiddle with the tree and the slider....the slider creates when a rigth click on the item of a tree panel, and i've got a function "buscarcapa" inside of a controller "ControlUbicar" that search the layer by id , when the function find the layer then apply the opacity (change event of the slider), and the blur event of the slider I hide the slider and reset the variables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem changing the property id 'sliderOpacidad' of the slider to 'record.data.id'